# Drop multiple columns in Spark R dataframe

Tags: r, sparkr, drop

drop(table1, table1$Age)

How do I drop multiple columns using the above syntax.

I don't want to use something like drop(table1, c("Age","id")).

I want to reference columns using the $notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the $ notation with drop. Per the [SparkR 3.2.0 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html) the drop function only accepts a vector of column names.

As an alternative, you might enjoy using the select function to keep the columns you want, the select function does handle the $ notation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(SparkR)

x <- data.frame(LABELS=letters,NUMBERS=1:26,SQRT_NUM=sqrt(1:26)) %>%
      as.DataFrame()

select(x,x$LABELS,x$NUMBERS) %>%
  display()
```